# Caused by: IllegalArgumentException: Wrong basePath for the root path

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, databricks

I am writing a dataframe which has column id with .partitionBy("id") on Id column

```
s3a://bucket/abc/id=0 
s3a://bucket/abc/id=1
```

but while reading from s3a://bucket/abc/id=1
I am getting below error -

**Caused by: IllegalArgumentException: Wrong basePath s3a://bucket/abc/id=1 for the root path: s3a://bucket/abc/id=0/part-1.c000.snappy.parquet**

can anyone please help, I am stuck with this

Comment: show the code that you're using to read data

Comment: spark.read.parquet("s3a://bucket/abc/id=0") ---so first time it works well and reads everything, but while reading from spark.read.parquet("s3a://bucket/abc/id=1") it fails and gives above error - thanks for looking into

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, but are you using streaming dataframes? You might be using the same checkpoint for multiple different source streams accidentally!

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Your shot in the dark hit the bullseye for me! Thank you.